# Ambient Light Sensor + Comparator

Tags: led, switches, comparator, phototransistor

So I've been looking at options to create a way of controlling whether a flash will fire based on the amount of light in the surrounding environment.

**Early note: Everything has to be surface mount and tiny**

One of the companies I contacted about an ambient light sensor says an ALS would work to turn the circuit on\off only if I used a comparator.

I threw together a quick circuit, except with a phototransistor, and this is what I have, but the problem is I feel the amperage really sucks. I can't pull more than 14mA for a single LED (I need closer to 50mA), and about 8mA for two in parallel. So I must have something wrong, or maybe a comparator just can't source more than that?

[image: Comparator]

Option 2 is using Transistors, which this circuit shows to source more, but still a bit under what I'd like.

[image: Transistor]

So I'd like to know what you guys think. Do you think either of these will work with something like [this](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/143/201407061531031645-365293.pdf)? Is there a better way to do this? As always, thank you guys a ton!

Comment: Why not use a transistor with the comparator?

Comment: At which point? I tried one under the LED, but it didn't work.

Comment: A high-side PNP switch with a pullup.

Comment: I'm still sort of a beginner, so I understand transistors, but I'm not sure what a pullup is. If you could elaborate a bit, it'd be a huge help :) Many thanks

Comment: C1 ... it amuses me

Comment: I saw C1 that way in about 4-5 similar schematics.

Answer (score 1):

Connect a transistor after the comparator to amplify the current.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWcFbZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If you are using a push-pull comparator (which LM311 is not) then you may be able to remove R2 if the comparator is powered from V+ and its high output is very close to V+.

And yes, the current output of the LM311 is in the single-digit mA. This additionally means that you may need a Darlington transistor for Q1.

Comment: Ok, this makes so much more sense now. Thank you tons.